# Why am I getting content type of a PDF file is returned as HTML?

Tags: java, url, web-crawler, mime-types, content-type

I am trying to see the content type of a web URL using the following code.

Interestingly, the content type of the given URL (`http://www.jbssinc.com/inv_pr_pdf/2007-05-08.pdf"`) is returned as `text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` even though it is a PDF document. I would like to understand why.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException{
    URLConnection urlConnection = null;
    URL url  = new URL("http://www.jbssinc.com/inv_pr_pdf/2007-05-08.pdf");
    try {
        urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10*1000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10*1000);
        urlConnection.connect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in establishing connection.\n");
    }
    String contentType = "";
    /* If we were able to get a connection ---> */
    if (urlConnection != null) {
        contentType = urlConnection.getContentType();
    }
    System.out.println(contentType);
}
```

Comment: talk to whoever set up that site. this has nothing to do with your code. andjust because the url ends in `.pdf` doesn't mean the site has to actually serve up pdf data. that could very well be an html page with "please log in to view file" or whatever.

Comment: @dsh, does anyone provide the content type or is it something that is automatically detected by the server?

Comment: I just sent a request (using Firefox) to that URL and it responded with `Content-Type: application/pdf`.

Comment: @RushdiShams Well-run sites provide the correct Content-Type header.  (I deleted my earlier comment because I tried it to see if the response was actually a login form and received the correct Content-Type header in the response)

Comment: @dsh, then why am I getting the content type as html when I am using the code?

Comment: If durron597's answer is correct, try setting the 'User-Agent' header in your request to look like your program is Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I access this page in Java, if I attempt to actually load the page, I get a **403 - Forbidden** error. These error pages are HTML pages, not pdf files, so that's why you're getting the content type you're seeing.

This site is probably detecting your browser or using some other mechanism to prevent automatic downloads, that's why it works in Chrome, Firefox and IE but not with Java.

Your code works fine with a different URL, such as `https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xml/AdobeXMLFormsSamples.pdf`.

In the case of this webserver, if you specify the `User-Agent` to a typical browser value, it will allow you to make the connection normally.

Try adding this line immediately before `urlConnection.connect()`:

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
```

[See this answer for more information about setting the `User-Agent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9828691/1768232). You should make sure you are not violating the website's Terms of Service in some way before doing this, though.

Typically, the way to check if a website is explicitly forbidding apps from downloading their content is with the `http://example.com/robots.txt` file. In this case, that would be http://www.jbssinc.com/robots.txt. In this case, this file doesn't forbid robots (your program) from downloading this particular file, so I think you are okay to spoof your User Agent. In this case, the fact that Java is blocked is more likely to be user error.

Further reading: [Is using a faked user agent allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20926097/1768232)

Comment: thanks for your answer. How do I know that by setting the User-Agent I am not violating the TOS of the website. Where should I find it?

Comment: That is nice @durron597 and I am actually obeying robots.txt. How about spoofing User-Agent? Do you know of any implication regarding this spoofing? I know that this is not directly related to my question posted here but it is so indirectly.

Comment: @RushdiShams [IANAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL), the tech is my expertise, not the law. However, you may find this useful: [Is using a faked user agent allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20926097/1768232)